# PyGTK: upon profiling, gtk.main() takes more time than expected, how do I know if this is reasonable?

Tags: python, gtk, profiling, pygtk

My program is a visualizer that is constantly updating the display. I am trying to optimize it to increase the framerate, and my largest cost is gtk._gtk.main:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    9.159    9.159   45.476   45.476 {gtk._gtk.main}
      868    8.146    0.009    9.884    0.011 xyz.py:291(gfx_transform_queue)
      868    7.705    0.009   12.657    0.015 xyz.py:322(gfx_draw_queue)
      868    3.886    0.004    7.755    0.009 xyz.py:240(gfx_queue_atoms)
   868000    2.638    0.000    4.952    0.000 xyz.py:365(gfx_draw_circle)
  7027010    2.111    0.000    2.111    0.000 xyz.py:314(cmp_queue)
  1736000    2.015    0.000    2.015    0.000 {method 'draw_arc' of 'gtk.gdk.Drawable' objects}
   869844    1.728    0.000    1.728    0.000 {numpy.core._dotblas.dot}
      868    1.635    0.002    3.746    0.004 {sorted}
   869872    1.261    0.000    1.261    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
      933    1.100    0.001    1.100    0.001 {method 'get_pointer' of 'gtk.gdk.Window' objects}
```

Is this reasonable behavior, or is it possible I am doing something wrong to make gtk.main suck up a lot of time?

Comment: The gtk._gtk.main is the event dispatcher, over which you have no control at all. The cumtime is roughly the sum of costs of all gui methods it will call itself. Look how many of them you need in this example, ~10M. 9s for dispatching them is still modest.

Comment: @janislaw I must be blind; where are you getting the ~10M number? Maybe I am making too many gui calls.

Comment: Sorry, that's probably ~1.7M looking at the draw_arc method. Still, I keep to my previous arguments. That's still a lot of work for dispatcher, and I'm not sure if there's analogous competing framework, that would perform much better. IMO you could speed up by resorting to opengl / directx, but then Python itself may slow you down.

Comment: Thanks - it's at least good to know I am not doing something outrageously stupid. I wish I could use opengl, but this has to go over network, so AFAIK, that's a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interpreting the profiling data wrong.
gtk.main() is really just running your program as the user interacts with it. What you're seeing is that it takes time to run your program, not gtk.main() itself.